# When multiple processes write to the same file, the file is overwritten, how could I avoid this overwriting?

Tags: c, windows

I am using CreateFile to create a file, then I use WriteFile to write in it.
The problem is when more processes write at the same time the file is overwritten.
These are the parameters used to call the function:

```
CreateFile( FileName, GENERIC_WRITE | GENERIC_READ,
            FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE | FILE_SHARE_DELETE,
            NULL, OPEN_ALWAYS, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL );
```

Comment: So you don't actually like FILE_SHARE_WRITE.  Low odds that you like read sharing either, generally only comes to a good end on a text file that you only append to.

Answer (score 1):

When you want to disable shared writes by multiple processes to your file, dont use `FILE_SHARE_WRITE` flag:

```
CreateFile( FileName, GENERIC_WRITE | GENERIC_READ,
            FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_DELETE,
            NULL, OPEN_ALWAYS, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL );
```

When these processes are communicating through writes to this file, synchronize these writes, for example by using events.